# How specify generated folder(Directory) Name in C#

Tags: c#, date-formatting

I have a C# application (WCF soap service) that is creating PDF documents and save in in the path that is defined in `web.config`. Consider for example path is: `C:\Doc\Pdf\`  that in the code path is in **location** variable. I like to generate folders for each day and stores the pdfs for that day on its folder.

I tried to use `CreateDirectory` but I don't know how specify name of the folder to generate.

This code only save the PDF in the `C:\Doc\Pdf\` and it is not creating any directory:

```
string pdfFileName = "Application" + "_" + documentData.APPLICATIONDATE.ToString("MMddyyyy") + "_" + documentData.APPLICATIONDATE.ToString("hhmmsstt") + "_" + documentData.BorrowerLastName;

location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PdfPath"].ToString();

DirectoryInfo di =System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(location);

wordDoc.SaveAs(location + pdfFileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

Comment: You're doing almost the same with the filename. What stops you from adding like `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` to `location`?

Comment: @CodeCaster but in the first step  DirectoryInfo di =System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(location); does not create any directory at all.

Comment: Then the directory already exists, or it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context I think that you could simply use the [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) method passing the combined path that you expect to be created.

The Directory method called CreateDirectory works creating all the directories missing in the path specified and if the path already exists doesn't throw exceptions, it simply does nothing

So your code coulde be

```
string dayPath = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string newPath = Path.Combine(location, dayPath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
........
```